# Local HTML Cache policy in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequest, nsurlcache

I have walked through various solution to clear the local image cache in UIWebView, while i trying to load the image in html it atomically  displays the previous image(i using the same name to replace the image in template).

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[CustomFunctions getFilesPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:obj]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
[webview1 loadRequest:request];
[webview1 reload];
```

this is my code and can any one please suggest me to do this. Thanks in advance. sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

//to prevent internal caching of webpages in application

```
NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];
//[sharedCache release];
sharedCache = nil;
```

try using this. It will clear the url cache memory of your application.

Comment: make your webview nill and initialize it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:NSURLRequest];
```

This would remove a cached response for a specific request. There is also a call that will remove all cached responses for all requests ran on the UIWebView:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

Comment: @iOSCreator i have posted my answer please check it.